# kubernetes: Role of selector in service vs deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-deployment

From the [official example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/) of `Kubernetes` documentation site on deploying a `Wordpress` application with mysql:

The service definition of `mysql`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
```

The deployment definition of `mysql`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: mysql
```

My question is the following:

The `Deployment` definition, has a `matchLabel` `selector`, so that it will **match** the pod defined below that has the `app: wordpress` **and** `tier:mysql` labels.

Why the `Service` `selector` does not require a `matchLabel` directive for the same purpose? What is the "selection" of service performed upon?

Answer (score 2):

The `Service` is a concept that makes your container (in this case hosting wordpress) available on a given port. It maps an external port (the `Node's` port) to and internal port (the container/pod's port). It does this by using the `Pod's` networking capabilities. The selector is a way of specifying in the service which `Pod` the port should be opened on. The `Deployment` is actually just a way of grouping things together - the `Pod` itself holds the Wordpress container, and the port that's defined in the service is available through the `Pod` networking.

This is a simple explanation, there are different kinds of services.

Comment: Btw, the best way to learn this is just set up a cluster and use kubectl commands to do things like describe pods, describe services. And use telnet or openssl to confirm the open ports exposed by your service.

Answer (score 2):

According to the K8S documentation on [Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/).

> The API currently supports two types of selectors: equality-based and set-based.
>
> Newer resources, such as Job, Deployment, Replica Set, and Daemon Set, support set-based requirements as well.

Looks like new resources like Deployment support more featured set-based (with matchLabels) and the old resources like Services follow the old equality-based (without matchLabels).